# Перезапуск кода при пробуждении из фонового режима

Tags: xcode

Суть приложение в том что бы сравнить текущую дату с заданным и вывести для каждого дня текст (время молитв)... Проблема: когда приложение находится в фоновом текст для текущего дня не показывает. Если закрыть приложение и после открыть все показывает правильно. Помогите пожалуйста! СПАСИБО!

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *utr;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *voskh;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *obed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *predz;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *vecher;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noch;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
       NSDateComponents *comp0 = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateComponents *comp1 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp2 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp3 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp4 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [comp1 setDay:1]; [comp1 setMonth:1];
    [comp2 setDay:2]; [comp2 setMonth:1];
    [comp3 setDay:3]; [comp3 setMonth:1];
    [comp4 setDay:4]; [comp4 setMonth:1];

if([comp1 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
   [comp1 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

    _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:58"; _predz.text=@"14:12"; _vecher.text=@"16:31"; _noch.text=@"18:01";
}

    if([comp2 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp2 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

 _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:58"; _predz.text=@"14:13"; _vecher.text=@"16:31"; _noch.text=@"18:01";


    }

    if([comp3 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp3 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

_utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:59"; _predz.text=@"14:14"; _vecher.text=@"16:32"; _noch.text=@"18:02";
    }

    if([comp4 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp4 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

_utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"12:00"; _predz.text=@"14:15"; _vecher.text=@"16:33"; _noch.text=@"18:03";
    }
```

Comment: весь этот код надо заново запускать когда приходит нотификация, что приложение стало активным

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko  Да да.. )) Но как?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationwillenterforegroundnotification?language=objc

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если бы я мог из такой информации вытащить пользу...

Comment: swift или objc?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подписаться на уведомление:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(myCoolSelector:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:NULL];
```

Выполнить метод:

```
- (void)myCoolSelector:(NSNotification*)notification
{
//ваш код здесь
}
```

не забыть отписаться в деаллоке

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот специально для Вас на [русском](http://vasya.livejournal.com/33548.html)

На все эти методы есть системные оповещения, добавьте обсервер на *applicationDidBecomeActive*, при этом событии перезагружайте функцию вычисления текста, то есть надо вынести код, который у вас во *viewDidLoad* в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее в двух случаях: *viewDidLoad* и событие applicationDidBecomeActive.

**Update**
пример:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) -> Void in
reloadScreenText()
})
```

теперь когда приложение вернется в активный режим, в вашем контроллере вызовется метод *reloadScreenText()*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928126/how-can-i-use-applicationdidbecomeactive-in-uiviewcontroller   нашел аот это но не могу интегрировать его в мое приложение... там где selector - написано ваш метод. Какой метод туда надо поставить. applicationDidBecomeActive это же метод delegate. Его же нельзя viewcontroller поставит.

Comment: В iOS есть NSNotificationCenter, в который приходят оповещения как от системы, так и созданые приложением (программистом), Вы можете добавить Observer для какого либо оповещения, в данном случае для applicationDidBecomeActive. я добавлю пример на swift в ответ.